# Dynamic sorting of tables on BIRT without javascript

Tags: report, birt

I am using WebViewerExample as my reporting.

I am designing reports within Eclipse using report designer.

I have a table with several columns. Data is retrieved from database.

Is there an easy way to dynamically sort the tables by clicking on the column header names?

I tried to pass string as a sorting condition, but it ain't helping.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried adding an ORDER BY to the query and ten parameterizing it?  You may need to do some REALLY lightweight scripting in order to massage the underlying query at run-time.  All that we are talking about is doing a string replace on the sort condition in the query.

Original Query:

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4
FROM Table1
WHERE Something = Something
ORDER Col1 ASC
```

The beforeOpen Event on the Data Set:

```
this.queryText = this.queryText.replace("Col1", "Your new Sort Spec");
```

That will do the trick.  Good Luck!

Comment: This won't sort the data on clicking header only when the report is loaded.

Comment: You would simply refresh the control on the header click, thereby refreshing the query & the underlying sort.  This does involve a round-trip to the DB for each sort, but it gets the job done.  Of course the best way to do this (and a whole lot more) is to use the BIRT viewer but that was not part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

There is an easier way, if you have a default.

First set up a paramater, as the sort criteria, in my case, I called it 'sort'.
Then select the table, go to the sorting tab, and use the folowing expression:
row[params["sort"].value].

This will sort the table by the parameter you pass in. You will need to make sure though that the column names are correct.

Answer (score 1):

do sort or filter parameter in report could'nt be a solution

- birt iserver with interactive web viewer do sort
- i try to do less but chipest (just open)

so change the viewer to do the job and not the report

http://dev.sonid.fr/BirtViewer/
( put your mouse on column header )